# Pass on the form data from one component to another

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to get information from a form via button which is not part of the component where the form is present.

Basically the current structure looks like this:

->Component A (button is here)
--> Inside component A I import another component (B) where the form is located

So I am trying to pass the information from component B, using button which is located in component A.

The reason why component B is not just part of component A (would make things relatively easier) is because it's used in several other places.

In component A I have:

```
    `<ComponentB></ComponentB>
    <div class="padding">
        <button @onSubmit="onSubmit" class="add-button btn btn-md float- 
        right" 
        type="submit">Add items from component B</button>
    </div>`
```

This is my data located in export default in component A

import ComponentB from './ComponentB';
import {mapActions} from 'vuex';

`export default {
    name: "ComponentA",
    components:{
        ComponentB
    },
    data(){
        return{
            firstname: '',
            surname: '',
            dateOfBirth: '',
            isPolicyHolder: '',
            drivingLicence:
            licenceNumber: '',
            countryLicenced: '',
            coverEffectiveFrom: '',
            coverEffectiveTo: '',
        }
    }`

I also have vuex state where I'm trying to pass the information to on button click.

In Component A this is the method:

```
    `methods:{
    ...mapActions(['addDriver']),
    onSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.addDriver( this.firstname, 
                        this.surname, 
                        this.dateOfBirth,
                        this.isPolicyHolder,
                        this.licenceNumber,
                        this.countryLicenced,
                        this.coverEffectiveFrom,
                        this.coverEffectiveTo)
    }
}`
```

Component B just hold few text boxes and date pickers.

So to summarise, on button click it should take whatever info is typed in component B to component A data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a Vuex state to manage the variables. And then, create the actions and mutates to modify the state. After that, you can just get what you want in component B.

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    // your states
  },
  mutations: {
    // change state here sync
  },
  actions: {
    // call mutations here, but you can do this async as axios methods etc..
  },
  getters: {
    // need this only if state still needs some calculation.
  }
}
```

So after you create all this. You'll be able to call the actions like above

```
this.$store.dispatch('ACTION')
```

and get the state in component B

```
this.$store.state.stateYouWant
```

or with getters

```
this.$store.getters.getterYouCreated
```

Comment: Hi, I do have a a vuex state manager created. Not entirely sure where to call that action though? $store.dispatch('ACTION'), in component B or A? Component B holds all the textboxes component A holds the button that meant to be clicked in order to add stuff to the state from component B..

Comment: so you have to pass this state to store first in component A. you have to call an action in component A to store the state. Component B you only will need the state. got it?